# Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT could not be found Error

Tags: .net, c++, deployment, vc90

I have a .NET application that references some C++ assemblies. My application requires the Visual C++ 9 runtimes  to be installed on the machine to run. If I download and install the runtime setup vcredist_x86.exe everything works fine.
However I would like to know if it possible to just include the dlls that I need along with my application as opposed to run a setup.
If I put the msvcr90.dll, msvcr90.dll, msvcp90.dll in the same folder as my executable, I still get the SideBySide error Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.CRT could not be found Error ..
What else am I missing here ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason MS wants you to use the redist is that so many people messed up installing the dll's on their own in the past (Not checking version of already installed dll's, failing to update shared refcount etc)

Only windows 2000 supports stuffing the dll's in system32, XP and later requires the manifest (But it is still possible to [deploy it as a private assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235291%28v=vs.80%29.aspx))